# How to remove this pattern from a string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have this string in:

> clsfd_registration_4371472

in this

```
<div  class="col-sm-1 hidden-xs text-right" id="clsfd_registration_4371472">
```

and I want to remove the last underscore followed byt a 7 digits sequence using regex in PHP.

How can I do it?
The following remove 7 digits but not the underscore.

```
^_\d{7}$^
```

Thank you

Comment: Despite the inappropriate delimiter choice, this *does* work with a simple `preg_replace`. Care to explain *how* you tried it?

Comment: Why regex and not a substr?

Comment: @mabi I would like to know it using substr if so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove only underscore, use:

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\bid="clsfd_registration)_(?=\d{7}")/', '', $str);
```

See demo **[here](http://ideone.com/pzWoVI)**.

---

If you want to remove also digits, use:

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\bid="clsfd_registration)_\d{7}(?=")/', '', $str);
```

See demo **[here](http://ideone.com/hLdaOZ)**.

Answer (score -1):

Since an id is unique, you only need:

```
$html = preg_replace('~\bid\s*=\s*["\']?clsfd_registration\K_[0-9]{7}\b~', '',
                     $html, 1);
```

pattern details:

```
\b           # word bounday (border between a char from \w class and another char
id
\s*          # possible white character here
=
\s*
["\']?       # can have single, double or no quotes at all
clsfd_registration
\K           # the \K reset all the match before it
_[0-9]{7}
\b           # to be sure that there is not another digit after
```

Another way:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($yourhtmlstring);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@id, "clsfd_registration_")]');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $node->setAttribute('id', preg_replace('~_[0-9]{7}$~', '', $node->getAttribute('id'),1));
}
$yourhtmlstring = $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: No answer = No reason